# Calculating HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage total length

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created an ActionFilter to try to control data usage by our API clients so that we can pinpoint misbehaving clients. The action filter is trivial:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CollectDeviceDataUsageAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
        if (actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("id")) {
            long id = (long)actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionArguments["id"];
            var action = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToUpper();
            var method = actionExecutedContext.Request.Method.Method;
            var resource = method + " " + action;
            IntegraRepository.CollectDeviceUsage(id.ToString(), resource, actionExecutedContext.Request, actionExecutedContext.Response);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

It delegates the data usage calulcation to the CollectDeviceUsage method. The trouble is: I don't know how I can get the actual "byte" size of both the Request and the Response! I can get the Content-Lenght of each, but that won't take into account the Headers. This doesn't need to be a super-ultra-accurate measure of data usage, I'm not interested in TCP/IP overhead, but the HTTP headers overhead I believe is enough to consider.

Here is the code I use to get the cotent-lengh:

```
var sizeReq = request.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0;
var sizeResp = response == null ? 0 : response.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0;
```

How could I also collect the actual Headers received/to be sent lenght? Something like request.Content.Headers.Length :-)

**UPDATE**

It was very simple to get the Request's header's length:

```
request.Headers.ToString().Length;
```

The trouble now lies only with the Respone headers. I believe I don't have enough information at the OnActionExecuted method to figure out the Headers that will be sent to the client, as the response.Headers return an empty collection!

Comment: This does it as a byproduct of implementing HEAD http://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/adding-http-head-support-to-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @MatthewMartin I've figure it out after trying to iterate through all the items in the request.Headers collection that the ToString method returns a string with the request headers concatenated. So I'm now using its Length as the headers lenght (I've updated the question). The problem now lies with the response as it seems I don't have enough information to know which headers Web.API will send out in the response to the client at the time my filter is run...

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a `ResultFilter` and do your processing in [`OnResultExecuted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onresultexecuted(v=vs.98).aspx) method.

You need to ensure that your filter is the last one to run, so make sure you specify [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterscope(v=vs.98).aspx) scope. This would ensure that your filter runs last even if other result filters are present.

You may find this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx) about filter order and scope helpful (scroll to Filter Order section).

Comment: You're genius! The more I learn ASP.NET MVC the more I love it. Since I'm learning it by osmosis, I don't grok the inernals (yet) but whenever I need something it seems to be well-thought! Thank you again...

Comment: The only problem now is that ResultExecutingContext don't provide an easy way to get the Action context that I need to get action name, etc. I'll have to use RouteData. I'll post the solution soon.

Comment: Yeah, you win some you lose some. Can't think off top of my head, maybe I'll try when i get in front of my PC.

Comment: No need to worry! I can get it from RouteData easily.