# Xamarin Forms - Determine Size of HttpRequestMessage & HttpResponseMessage objects

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm working on a multi-platform mobile application using Xamarin.Forms where many API calls are made to send and retrieve data from a mobile device. I would like to try and make an estimate of the amount of mobile data that is being used by each API call by looking at the header & content lengths on both the HttpRequestMessage & HttpResponseMessage objects that are sent and retrieved by an HttpClient's SendAsync method call.

I did some initial research and found this prior Stack Overflow question from several years ago that I used as my initial basis: [Calculating HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage total length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064840/calculating-httprequestmessage-and-httpresponsemessage-total-length). While it seems to work in some ways, I have noticed that there is a discrepancy in my calculated size vs. what gets reported by the web proxy software I'm using to analyze the requests that are being made (Charles Web Debugging Proxy) during my code testing.

This is what my code is doing to try to calculate size at the moment (Edited per comment request to include code that shows how the request is sent):

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip,
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100,
    UseProxy = true,
};

var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler, true);
var requestUriString = "UriGoesHere";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUriString);
// Code to add some headers with TryAddWithoutValidation(string, string) before sending the request goes here
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);

// Code to try & get request & response sizes - this information is not accurate with what I'm seeing in Charles
var requestSize = request?.Content?.Headers?.ContentLength ?? 0;
requestSize += request?.Headers?.ToString()?.Length ?? 0;
var responseSize = response?.Content?.Headers?.ContentLength ?? 0;
responseSize += response?.Headers?.ToString()?.Length ?? 0;
var totalSize = (requestSize + responseSize) / 1024.0;

var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
// code continues that logs the totalSize & processes the data read in the stream object
```

Here are the main issues that I'm trying to work out.

1. On UWP only, the response's content headers always reports the ContentLength as null. I can see the proper content length being reported in the Charles proxy, but I can't access this value from code. GZip compression is being used to compress the size of the response content, and this seems to be factoring into this issue, as if I take this compression out, ContentLength starts reporting a proper value in code. With this compression still in, if I try to do something like this method call, response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync(), to read the data from the response, it does populate the ContentLength, but its the uncompressed size (and not the compressed size like I'm looking for).
2. When I try to get the size of the headers using request/response.Headers.ToString().Length, I get a value, but it doesn't match the size reported by Charles, so the values are off. Is there a different way to get the proper header size?
3. The request & response objects don't seem to have a way to report the amount of data used by the TLS Handshake that happens whenever a web connection is established. Is this something that needs to be accounted for, and if so, is there a way to programmatically look this up on the request or response?

At this point, I'm just looking for any information that can guide me in the right direction here. Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible? If so, is this the best way to estimate the amount of data that would be used on a per request basis? Or is there a better method that I haven't thought of or encountered yet? I couldn't find anything specifically within Xamarin Forms that seemed to do any sort of data usage tracking over a certain period of time, but if something like that exists, that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: there are a ton of existing questions on this topic.  The fact that it's Xamarin should really not matter.  See https://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient+get+request+size+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Can you share the code that you used to send request ? Can you check if you have set httpRequest Content property ?

Comment: @Nico Zhu-MSFT I edited my original post to include the code used to send the request & get the HttpResponseMessage for the Http Get case. In this case, Content is not set on the Request, but if I am doing a Post or a Patch, I will set Content & I can get the ContentLength properly from that.

The issue is that on UWP only, the HttpResponseMessage is not including Content-Length in the header when AutomaticDecompression is set. If I take that line out of the HttpClientHandler constructor, then it is included. I'm looking to see if there's any way I can get the compressed length on UWP.

Comment: *the HttpResponseMessage is not including Content-Length in the header when AutomaticDecompression is set.* Can you explain that? why you get the content length from header ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I'm interested in getting the Content-Length from the header of the HttpResponseMessage because I want to know the compressed size of the response's content. The exact same code works on iOS & Android the way I want it to, so at this point I'm just trying to figure out why UWP doesn't work the same way as the other two platforms and to see if there is any way that we can get the compressed size on UWP.

Comment: in general, we use Windows.Web.Http namespace  In uwp, and I'm afraid `System.Web.Http` is not compatible with UWP platform.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew Thank you for the information. System.Web.Http is pretty heavily used by this particular mobile application, so I have some concerns about how much effort it would take to move from System.Web.Http to Windows.Web.Http. Also, since this is a multi platform app that does need to support Android & iOS as well, would Windows.Web.Http work on those platforms, or just UWP?

Comment: You may need dependency servicer to generate new  `Windows.Web.Http` httpclient for UWP platform. and use `Onplatform` to detect current platform to chose use which method.